# Laravel 5.4 Session Timeout Redirect Path

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Where can i set the redirect path when session timeout? If i am not mistaken, by default, laravel will redirect to /login but instead of this, I want to redirect to something like this /admin/login. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for function **unauthenticated()** located at : **app/Exceptions/Handler.php**

Comment: so when session timeout, function unautheticated() will be executed?

Comment: ya, when session is timedout, the user becoms unautheticated, and every request that he made, and that need to be auth is catched by that function unautheticated()

Comment: Can i know is there any event listener that listen on session timeout?

Comment: @user3681740 How to you know unauthenticated() was called BECAUSE of session timeout vs. because I tried to access a page before I was authenticated?